# Hibernate mapping unsuccessful - don't know where the error is occuring

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

I looked on stack overflow to find different causes and permutations that will lead to this problem, but I don't think this situation has been asked yet.

## Error

I'm trying to use hibernate with spring MVC on Maven, and for some reason the mapping of the hibernate.cfg.xml is not correctly mapping(I checked my path, I THINK it is correct). I'm getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller.Entry
```

with this mapping:

```
<mapping class="com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller.Entry" />
```

inside my hibernate.cfg.xml file.

## File structure

This is my file structure:

#### From project explorer

[image]

#### from navigator

[image]

For those who are interested - some specific files:

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">NAMEHERE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>

        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller.Entry" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <!--  name of the servlet will add a -servlet postfix 
        unless otherwise specified. -->
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> <!-- is the class for which to find the servlet -->
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### Very simple POJO for hibernate

```
package com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ENTRY_DATE")
public class Entry {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    int entryInfo;
    Date date;

    public int getEntryInfo() {
        return entryInfo;
    }

    public void setEntryInfo(int entryInfo) {
        this.entryInfo = entryInfo;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

### What I think might be the error

- I think it might be because my hibernate.cfg.xml isn't finding the src/main/resources (for some reason my project doesn't have that) and so it can't find the bean. This is how I created the project: new->Dynamic Web Project, After creation: -> configure -> configure to Maven project. This way, for some reason I don't see the src/main/resources or src/main/java. My src file is just by itself. I tried to manually add the files via directory and the pom.xml rejected it, and I had to rollback to original changes. The thing is, I have my spring jars in maven and it DID find my controller, which was near the same directory.
- There's something wrong with my hibernate POJO Entry.java(but I think it's unlikely since it's so simple)
- Typo perhaps?(Really unlikely, I looked all over the place)

EDIT: There are some speculation that perhaps I didn't download the correct jars for hibernate. Here's my Maven dependencies tab.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your configuration. Hibernate 5.0.0 is meant to work with Spring 4.2.0 which I see you have but perhaps you could try with hibernate-core-4.3.7 or some lesser version just to check it's not a dependency version issue ?

Comment: @smoggers yup that was the issue! Darn it Hibernate 5.0.0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the hibernate jars are correctly added as dependencies in your pom.xml
You can check this by using the Hibernate annotation (org.hibernate.annotations.Entity) instead of JPA annotation (javax.persistence.Entity) in your Entry class.
If the Jar is not properly imported, your project will not be built successfully.

Comment: Hi! I tried that by importing org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(which showed up as deprecated) and then compiling. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes. org.hibernate.annotations.Entity is deprecated. It is recommended to use JPA annotation. The problem you have should be that the hibernate jars are not available at rum time. You should add it to your pom.xml and build and package it using Maven.

Comment: I think I have the correct packages in my Maven configurations though.. Here, I'll attach a picture of my dependencies in my question.

Comment: Try adding below dependancy to your pom.xml and check. <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Hmm.. still doesn't work. Still returns `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller.Entry`

Comment: How do you build and package the application? Is it using Maven or using Eclipse?

Comment: I built a dynamic web project in eclipse, and then I configured it to be a maven project using the existing dynamic web project. The configuration is from a Maven plug-in. Should we move this to the java chat by the way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88961/discussion-between-ambegodas-and-oneraynyday).

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Finally it worked by changing the hibernate version to 4.3.6. Please replace your depandency with below and try.   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Entry.hbm.xml then try adding the path of the hbm.xml file too:

```
<mapping class="com.firstspringmvcproject.introcontroller.Entry" />
<mapping resource="com/firstspringmvcproject/introcontroller/Entry.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have an entry.hbm.xml - it's annotation based. Would I need one?

Comment: If it is annotation based, then you do not need an hbm.xml file. Do you have another class or it is just Entry class?

Comment: This is my only class for hibernate. The other is for spring and it works. It's just a controller.

Comment: Try the xml way, It is not the best choice but maybe works for your fisrt project.